# Return a class type from a function?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create an instance of a class which is returned from a function. Here is a playground script (that doesn't work) to explain what I would like:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyModel: NSManagedObject {

}

class A {
    func modelClass() -> NSManagedObject {
        return NSManagedObject.self
    }

    func doSomething() {
        // create an instance from modelClass()
        let instance = self.modelClass()

        // I need this:
        // let instance = NSManagedObject()
    }
}


class B : A {
    override func modelClass() -> NSManagedObject {
        return MyModel.self
    }
}

let a = A()
a.doSomething()
```

So..

- in the `A` class, I want `doSomething` to be able to create an instance of `NSManagedObject` and...
- in the `B` class, I want `doSomething` to be able to create an instance of `MyModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. modelClass(and the modelClass override in B) should return:

```
NSManagedObject.Type
```

i.e.

```
func modelClass() -> NSManagedObject.Type {
```

Comment: Just to be clear, they should not _return_ `NSManagedObject.Type`, they should _declare_ that they return `NSManagedObject.Type`. `.Type` is used in declarations, `.self` is used in passing the actual value.